# Initiate click on div using tab and enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I have a and div element

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>

<div tabindex="0">div</div>
```

And click event handlers

```
$("a").on("click",function(){
   alert(" a click")

});

$("div").on("click",function(){
    alert("div click")

});
```

Using keyboard tab I can navigate to a link ,press Enter and see alert,but I can't do this for div.

Is it possible initiate click event for div as same as for a tag,without using any other events(keypress)?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cosset777/jhf1by1v/)

Comment: Not all browsers support `tabindex=0` for divs - it is not allowed in w3c recommondation, keep that in mind! http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex

Comment: As Martin said. Everything need to be wrap in a link tag to be access with tab. It's a convention in accessibility.

Comment: HTML4 does not allow `tabindex` on `div` -- https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex -- but HTML5 _does_ allow it -- https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom event like this:

```
$("div").on("click enter",function(){
    alert("div click")

})
.on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
        $(this).trigger( 'enter' );
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/jhf1by1v/2/)

Comment: I wrote without using any other events(keypress).

Comment: Oops, did not see that ...... any particular reason why you have that requirement?

Comment: In my application I have some div,span,that have click events,and according to new requirments I need aceess to its using tab and enter.I know I wrap it to a tag,but it will change a lot of code

Comment: You could probably write a small plugin to do that for so that you transfer the burden of maintaining the `a` wrap around the `span` and `div` elements and what happens when `enter` is pressed to one place.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but i thought i might add something.

PeterKA has a nice solution but i would improve it just a bit.
Instead of triggering a new custom event like `enter` just trigger the `click` event. This way you don't need to modify existing code and add the new event to every listener you have.
Each element that listens to `click` will be triggered.

```js
$('.btn').on("click",function(){
    alert("div click")
})

// at a centrelized spot in your app
$('.btn').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 13) {
      $(this).trigger('click');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#firstDiv').focus(); // just focusing the first div
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstDiv" class="btn" tabindex="0">div</div>

<div class="btn" tabindex="0">div</div>

<div class="btn" tabindex="0">div</div>
```